# Sending data to stdin of another process waiting on ppoll

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

There is following code:

```
#include <poll.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pollfd pd;
  pd.fd = 0;
  pd.events = POLLIN;
  int ret = ::ppoll(&pd, 1, 0, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

This should wait for some data on stdin and wake up when data appears.

Running program this way, it seems that ppoll is woken up (passing data to stdin via a pipe):

```
$ echo 1 | ./main
$
```

However sending something to the process from another shell doesn't wake up ppoll:

First shell:

```
$ ./main
```

Second shell:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/$(pgrep main)/fd/0
```

After that I just see that in the first shell there is printed `1`, but ppoll doesn't wake up. How to send data correctly to a process's stdin from another shell so ppoll will wake up?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is clear. When you say *"sending something to the process from another shell"* do you mean from a different `tty`? If so, they have entirely different `stdin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simply impossible, unless the process was specially launched in a way that enables feeding data to it from outside (i.e. through a FIFO or a pipe).

Even though `/proc/$PID/fd/0` (i.e. standard input stream) points to the process's controlling terminal, so do (in the absence of redirection) `/proc/$PID/fd/1` and `/proc/$PID/fd/2` (i.e. standard output and standard error streams):

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep  6 01:36 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep  6 01:36 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep  6 01:36 2 -> /dev/pts/3
```

The terminal is a pseudo-device, that can be both read from and written to. When a process *reads* from it, the terminal provides data entered from the keyboard or by other means (e.g. pasted from the clipboard). When you *write* to a terminal, it displays the data. Now when you write to `/proc/$PID/fd/0` you write to the *terminal* rather than to the target process's standard input stream, that's why your data is displayed but the process stays indifferent.